# My scientific data was used by my colleague without my permission in a IEEE paper, is this misconduct?

Tags: ieee, research-misconduct

I am a scientist currently working on a project where there are several other partners. My job was to work with raw data, do analysis, create attributes, and prepare AI model. My other collegue's job was with hardware where he has to use my prepared data for hardware acceleration. I found out recently that he has recently published a paper where he used my data. He even had a chapter on data quality, attributes, and data length which is similar to one of my already published papers on the same data. After publishing the paper he told me that he acknowledged me in his paper for providing the data. I don't know if I should be overwhelmed that he used my prepared data(took me almost a year) for his paper without even asking me and never used me as a co-author. Is this okay in the research community? Am I overreacting?

Comment: This is hard to tell without details, and there are cultural aspects to this. Generally, building on *published* results does not need permission from any of the authors. The question is rather whether the dataset itself should be considered to be published, and that depends on what you wrote in joint publications. Depending on the culture, your colleague may have assumed an implicit permission by you....or not. Whether you should have been considered to be co-author depends on whether there was any intellectual contribution by you.

Comment: While the "research community's" probably has no 100% uniform view on handling of datasets between colleagues, certainly every case that could be remotely seen as questionable warrants communication between dataset owner and user for unpublished datasets. Note that your "Copyright" tag is misleading because copyright is a legal matter, and not a matter of what is OK to the scientific community ("ethics of academia").

Comment: @DCTLib thanks for your answer. There was an intellectual contribution to it as I mentioned before. It was not any published result. I received the data from a 3rd party and process it to be usable in the next phase. The part of my data work was more than a year's job where I put my own methods and analysis for data preprocessing before it can be used by my colleague.  I agree with you that it depends on cultural differences. Not sure, if in any culture it is not required for permission to use someone's work before using it in a paper.

Comment: You wrote in your original post "...which is similar to one of my already published papers on the same data" - so there may have been the implicit assumption that the data itself is published, too. Regarding the culture: In fields in which the PIs have to bring in huge money to get anything done, datasets may be considered to primarily belong to the lab rather than the researcher working on the dataset (who in turn is paid from the money acquired for the lab). The lack of communicating with you *may* in such a setting be a simple mistake, especially if your PI was involved.

Comment: You write that the data was acquired from a 3rd party. Who signed what kind of agreement with the 3rd party? Did the agreement specify who was the primary academic user, and what could be done with the data?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, thank you for your comment. It was a govt. data which was signed by the university to work with. It specified the primary user which is my faculty and also mentioned it's working principle. I would be happy to explain you a little more. I, from the faculty used that raw data and had to preprocess it, analyze it, segragate it in different subsections based on requirements and finally modified the overall data to create a scientific model. My colleague used that preprocessed data and scientific model without my permission.

Comment: I want to add that often data and models/software/techniques are *technically* owned by the university or lab in which they are developed. So in some sense your permission was not required. And it may be (although this is field dependent) that simply processing data is not considered a contribution warranting authorship. Assuming that your prior work was cited properly (since you mention this was already published elsewhere) and you were acknowledged then I'm not convinced this was anything more than a communication breakdown.

Comment: @sErISaNo, I understood what you meant. Yes, the work belongs to the lab. Although, my supervisor apologized to me yesterday as he was the second author and told me that in the future he will check strictly if someone is using my contributed work without my permission or giving authorship. I decided to let it go afterward. I believe, not everyone has the decency or collaborative mentality.